# Separating a file with embedded header records into two files

Tags: files

I would like to separate the following example text file into two separate files based on the embedded header record using a unix script:

```
CSI 447907 890947967201270
776666666   B
771555555   B
774444444   B
REL 447904 890947967201270
772222222   A
771111111   B+
770000000   A
CSI 447911 891096722201270
774444444   B+
778888888   A
779999999   A
REL 171077 889928722201270
774444444   B
773333333   B+
772222222   B+
771111111   C
PHY 114926 891987278201270
123456789   A
987654321   A
777777777   B+
```

The result files:

Text file 1

```
CSI 447907 890947967201270
776666666   B
771555555   B
774444444   B
CSI 447911 891096722201270
774444444   B+
778888888   A
779999999   A
```

Text file 2

```
REL 447904 890947967201270
772222222   A
771111111   B+
770000000   A
REL 171077 889928722201270
774444444   B
773333333   B+
772222222   B+
771111111   C
PHY 114926 891987278201270
123456789   A
987654321   A
777777777   B+
```

The number of header records can vary as well as the number of the detail records. The columns/fields are static. The first text file contains the CSI headers and corresponding detail records while the second is what is left over.

Comment: This smells an awful lot like homework. if you want people to do your homework for you, at least format your question properly.

Comment: Steven, what have you tried so far? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: An answer is any scripting language (geared towards text munging), like Perl, Python, Ruby or others.

Answer (score 3):

Another typical job for awk:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 LC_ALL=C awk '
  $1 ~ /^[A-Z]{3}$/ {
    if ($1 == "CSI")
      file = "csi.txt"
    else
      file = "rest.txt"
  }
  file {print > file}'
```

`POSIXLY_CORRECT` is only in case your `awk` is GNU awk that doesn't recognize the `{...}` unless in standard conformant mode.

`LC_ALL=C` is to make sure `[A-Z]` means the ASCII character from `A` to `Z`, otherwise, that range might include other characters depending on the localisation settings.

If on Solaris, use `command -p awk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` as otherwise you might end up with `/bin/awk` which should not be used any longer.

Answer (score 2):

I used a while loop and read down to the first CSI header. Then I was able to write the the header and detail records.

This is what I have thus far:

```
file="data.txt"
STR=CSI
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ ${line} = @(${STR}*) ]] then
    echo $line > file2.txt
    while IFS= read -r line2
    do
      echo $line2 >> file2.txt
    done
    fi
done <"$file"
```

Steven